# Why AWS OpenSearch service returns 404 when I try to reindex?

Tags: aws-serverless, opensearch

I have an **AWS OpenSearch Serverless collection** with one index called *index1*. It has some data in it that I need to reindex. I interact with the collection using the OpenSearch Dev Tools, through the OpenSearch Dashboard.

According to [OpenSearch documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.11/api-reference/document-apis/reindex/), I should be able to reindex the data by creating a second index then calling the _reindex API.

```
PUT index2

POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index2"
  }
}
```

The first operation (creating the index2) works just fine. The second one fails with a 404:

```
Request failed to get to the server (status code: 404)
```

After performing the first operation, if I call `GET _mappings`, I get the mappings of index1, which correspond to the data I have there, plus an empty object representing the lack of mappings for index2. The 404 response, therefore, makes no sense to me. Semantically, it means "not found", but what exactly wasn't found in this case? I know the domain exists, since all other operations are working. I know bot indexes exist, since I see the mappings.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like AWS Opensearch Serverless supports the reindex command.  Looking at the list of [support api operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/serverless-genref.html), reindex doesn't show up in the list.